# Will using PHP sleep() function work in CRON jobs

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter PHP we're using *CRON* jobs for calling one specific job. If I used `sleep()` function inside the script, will it affect (be used) in the `CRON` jobs?

I have run the below PHP file using cronjob daily(12pm) in server:

**test.php:**

```
function cron_function()
{
   while (true) {
    foreach ($results as $user) {
      if($user['email'] == 'test@gmail.com') {
        break;
      }
   sleep(1);
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you give some more details about that cronjob? How/when is the script executed and is the sleep function inside the cron script? Showing some code might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

> sleep() — Delays the program execution for the given number of seconds. Returns zero on success, or `FALSE` on error.

Referring to your question, the answer is *YES*. It doesn't matter for *PHP* whether you use `sleep()` in *CRON* jobs or not. The result will remain the same - the execution of the script will be delayed.

**Example:**

```
// Print current time
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";

// Sleep for 10 seconds
sleep(10);

// Wake up and print current time again
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
```

**Result:**

```
12:00:00
12:00:10
```